# I'm trying to display another lwc that is table within this tab from the JS file

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning

I know that I can replace `{layer.content}` with `<c-skills></c-skills>` tag and that it displays fine within the HTML file but is there a way for me to call it from the JS file and put it in the tab Content declaration? I know that putting it in quotes doesn't work and just pasting the tag in it as well won't work. My main goal is to add the '' from the js.
HTML:

```
<template >
        <!--Template for the content area-->
         <template for:each={tabs} for:item="layer">
             <div id={layer.ariaControls} class={layer.cssClass}  data-id={layer.Id} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={layer.Id}
                 key={layer.Id}>
                 {layer.Content}
             </div>
            </template>  
    </div>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    export default class masteriesAndFeats extends LightningElement {
        tabs = [{
            title: "Masteries",
            Content: "content1",
            Id: "tab-scoped-1__item",
            cssTab:"slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-is-active slds-size_1-of-2 tabStyle",
            cssClass: "slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-show",
            index: "0",
            ariaControls:"tab-scoped-1",
            selected: "true",
            
        }, {
            title: "Feats",
            Content: "Content2",
            Id: "tab-scoped-2__item",
            cssTab:"slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-size_1-of-2 tabStyle",
            cssClass: "slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide",
            index: "-1",
            ariaControls:"tab-scoped-2",
            selected: "false",
            
        }];
        handleClick(event) {
            this.tabs = this.tabs.map(tab => {
                if(tab.Id === event.target.dataset.link) {
                    tab.cssClass = "slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-show";
                    tab.index = "0";
                    tab.selected = "true";
                    tab.cssTab = "slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-size_1-of-2 slds-is-active tabStyle";
                } else {
                    tab.cssClass = "slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide";
                    tab.index = "-1";
                    tab.selected = "false";
                    tab.cssTab = "slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-size_1-of-2 tabStyle";
                }
                return tab;
              });
            }
    }
```